# Query add html after set amount of posts?

Tags: query-posts, customization

Is it possible to add some html after a set amount of posts?

For the purposes of a slider after 6 posts i need it to enclose in a div/li or whatever then start a new div/li for the next 6 and so on.

Here is my custom query which just prints the post name in a list.

```
<ul>

<?php $args=array('post_type' => 'courses','post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => -1);$my_query = null;$my_query = new WP_Query($args);if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>   

<li><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></li> 

<?php endwhile;} wp_reset_query();?> 

</ul>
```

After at the start and end of 6 posts i need to open a div then close it after the 6th post.

Is this possible with WordPress PHP?

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
<?php
$courses = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'courses',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    ) );

if ( $courses ) {
    print "\n" . '<div style="background:pink">';
    foreach ( $courses as $course_count => $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        the_title( "\n", '<br>' );
        if ( 5 == $course_count ) {
            print "\n" . '</div>';
            print "\n" . '<div style="background:yellow;">';
        }
    }
    print "\n" . '</div>';
}

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

a possible way:

```
<ul>  
<?php $args=array('post_type' => 'courses','post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => -1);$my_query = null;
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $count = 0; //initialize count variable    
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>      
        <?php if( $count%6 == 0 ) { ?>OUTPUT OPENING HTML TAG<?php } ?>       
    <li><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></li>    
        <?php if( $count%6 == 5 ) { ?>OUTPUT CLOSING HTML TAG<?php } ?>
        <?php $count++; ?>       
    <?php endwhile; }  ?>    
        <?php if( $count%6 != 0 ) { ?>OUTPUT CLOSING HTML TAG<?php } // in case there is not a multiple of 6 posts ?>       
<?php wp_reset_query();?>   
</ul>
```